# Subtract time from timer if answer is wrong, creating a quiz javascript

Tags: javascript

Creating a quiz for a project in class. Quiz is working, but I'm stumped at the timer. When you press the start button, the timer executes and begins to count down. How can I allow the timer to reduce in time when a wrong answer in the quiz is selected and submitted?

Thanks, sorry if I missed a post that answered this question already.

Code for the timer:

```
function startTimer(){
    console.log('timer suppose to go')
    var sec = 59;
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
        document.getElementById('timerDisplay').innerHTML='00:'+sec;
        sec--;
        if (sec < 0) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            alert("Time is up!")
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to ensure you have access to `sec` outside of that function, and then decrement (and update the display) when they get an incorrect answer:

```js
(function() {
    var sec = 60;
    function startTimer(){
        console.log('timer suppose to go')
        var timer = setInterval(function(){
            sec--;
            document.getElementById('timerDisplay').innerHTML='00:'+sec;
            if (sec < 0) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                alert("Time is up!")
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
    document.getElementById('incorrect').addEventListener('click', function() {
        sec -= 5;
        document.getElementById('timerDisplay').innerHTML='00:'+sec;
    });
    startTimer();
})();
```

```html
<div id="timerDisplay"></div>
<button id="incorrect">Simulate Incorrect Answer</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!